# Can I mark anotther guest as not attending in my google calendar event?

Tags: google-calendar

I've set up a google calendar event with a large number of guests - those who can attend generally just accept the invite, but those who send their apologies tend to ignore the invite and reply to the email giving the apologies leaving thier attendance as a '?' withing the calendar invitation itself... is there a way to manually mark an attendee as not attending? (that way I only need refer to one list, not an full inbox, for an accurate tally on attendees.

The only workaround I can think of is an auto email filter rule/manually replying asking them to click yes/no (which i already ask/point out) but that sounds a bit clunky.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go into the attendees reply email (if they respond to your original invitation) and the `Yes`/`No`/`Maybe` buttons in your original message which they responded to will work to mark their availability!

Comment: I tried to do this, but Google prompted me to enter the user's Google password.